# How to make Link from react-router-dom work further inside the application?

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<HashRouter>` wrapping the components which holds the `<Link>` components, however, I still get the error `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`. Is there some hierarchy that says you have to have the Links on a higher level than I have? I have the `<Link>`
inside a dropdown.
Something like my app is:

```
<HashRouter>
  <ComponentA>
    <ComponentB>
      <Link to="/my-path"/>
    </ComponentB>
  </ComponentA>
</HashRouter>
```

**EDIT:**
What I am doing is adding a `<Link>` inside a custom option inside a dropdown which I have gotten from a library. It says I can add custom elements into my dropdown options. The dropdown I am making is complex with buttons inside it, and I want to link to one place if you click the title. There is where the `Link` comes in. When I add the Link there, the error message appear, but not when I add the Link directly to the component which is using the dropdown. This is how I have the component, which is **not** working. This is just mocked data, the data I use are calculated inside a `.map`:

```
const CustomLink = () => <Link to="/some-path">Title of link</Link>;

const data = [{
    selected_key: 'id1',
    content: [<CustomLink />, <CustomButton />]
  },
  ...
]

return <DropdownFromLibrary data={data} />;
```

I want/need to add the components inside a array, but the above example does not work. This below do work, to have the Link inside the same component as the Dropdown, but is not what I want, since I need to calculate new path to every option:

```
return (
  <>
    <CustomLink />
    <DropdownFromLibrary data={data} />
  </>
);
```

***SOLUTION***

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const history = useHistory();
const CustomLink = ({ id, title }) => <div onClick={() => history.push(`/some-title/${id}`)}>{title}</div>
const data = [{
    selected_key: 'id1',
    content: [<CustomLink />, <CustomButton />]
  },
  ...
]

return <DropdownFromLibrary data={data} />;
```

Comment: There are no restrictions to where in a router the `Link` has to appear. You are likely missing something that you did not include in your question. If you can, please provide a minimal working example that reproduces the issue, e.g. in a codesandbox.

Comment: Also see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-bush-nceeh?file=/src/App.js) that demonstrates the code you presented is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error because the Link has to go inside the   < componentB> . I mean inside componentB's function. Wrap ur return elements inside the Link.

Comment: @RMT, Did it solve ur problem or you want me to further explain it. Plz let me know if my answer solved ur problem.